# Phasor analysis confusion in the trignometric identities

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, ac, analog

I was learning about phasor analysis from Fundamentals of electric circuits by Alexander and Sadiku.

In chapter 9 the below trigonometric identity is given.

[image]

As per my knowledge sin is positive in the 2nd quadrant and negative in all other quadrants(ALL SILVER TEA CUPS).
In the first equation **Sin(wt±180)** means it is lying in the 2nd quadrant and 3rd quadrant depending phase shift is +180 or -180.

When it is lying in the 2nd quadrant**(Sin(wt-180))**it should be positive and when it is lying in the 3rd quadrant **(Sin(wt+180))**should be negative.This is my understanding.

But in the book it is given as **Sin(wt±180)=-sinwt** .May I know where I went wrong

Comment: Just draw a sine wave and label it. You will see it with your eyes.

Comment: What's wrong with applying the good old double angle identities?

Comment: @Chu- We will get the answer using double angle identities,but I want to understand via quadrant way

Comment: *As per my knowledge sin is positive in the 2nd quadrant and negative in all other quadrants(ALL SILVER TEA CUPS).* - it is positive in the first quadrant too. (First time I hear about this mnemonic, had to google it. And it is quite stupid and just as confusing as PEMDAS and similar. There are quite few very simple definitions to remember or use logic instead of trying to understand these weird codes - and misinterpret them as you just did).

Answer (score -2):

Sine is negative in 1st and 3rd quadrant.

Comment: Maybe my definition of quadrants is different from yours, but in it sine is positive in first quadrant.

Comment: Yes, depends on how you define quadrants,but since the Op claimed it was + in 2nd quadrant, it would be consistent to say - in 1 & 3; + in 2 & 4.

Comment: Then maybe be better post your definition, because it seems to be substantially different from the common one.